# How do i get data from webpage using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to get data from a webpage using javascript and ajax only. My webpage is returning an array back, which I want to show on my html page. I can't use php with this.

This is the code i am using.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
        <script src="background.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php?url='http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2643743/3dayforecast.rss'",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp'
            });

            function callback(data){
                $('#iec_azn_data').html(data.results[0]);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        Hi
        <div id="iec_azn_data">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use success in ajax request. success: function(data){//your code}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a function to `success` in the `$.ajax` options. That function gets called when your request successfully returns.

```
$.ajax({
  url:"http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php?url='http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2643743/3dayforecast.rss'",
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success : function(data){
    //data is a variable containing the returned data
  }
});
```

Comment: Now i have this JavaScript But Still its not rendering any thing                                                        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php?url='http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2643743/3dayforecast.rss'",
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success : function (data){
                    $('#iec_azn_data').html(data.results[0]);

                }
            });
        </script>

Comment: @Keyur what is the return data? is it HTML or something else?

Comment: return data is simple html table

Comment: @Keyur can you verify it returned something by doing `console.log(data)`?

Comment: Where should i put this console.log(data) bcoz i am not familiar with ajax

Comment: @Keyur inside the success function

Comment: @Keyur it's in the console, not on the page

Comment: hi joseph it gives me this error Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.mydomain.com/page1.php?url='http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/2643743/3dayforecast.rss'/&callback=jQuery1910018362388014793396_1366029246213&_=1366029246214".